# How to Select then Insert on the same row before moving to next row

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to execute some code that would choose a row in my database, get a value within that row called `url` then do some work with that value that would return a string called `foo` then when it inserts the returned value `foo` into the database in a column called `category`

The code I have thus far is as follows

```
connection.query('select * from ttnews order by id DESC Limit 0,5'), function (error, results, fields) {

if (error) throw error;
//console.log(results[0]);
for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    console.log(results[i].id);
    textapi.classifyByTaxonomy({
    'url': results[i].externalurl,
    'taxonomy': 'iptc-subjectcode'
    }, function(error, response) {
    if (error === null) {
        response['categories'].forEach(function(c) {
            console.log(c.label);
            connection.query("update ttnews set category='"+c.label+"' WHERE id='"+results[i].id+"'"), function (error, results, fields) {
                if (error) throw error;
            }


        });
    }
    });
}
```

}

I fixed the quotes and brackets however now I am not getting any response from the console and the database is not being updated.

Any idea as to what is causing this error and do I have any other issues within this function

Comment: The single quotes should be inside the double quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your update seems you have wrong single double quote sequence

```
connection.query("update ttnews set category='" +c.label+ 
          "' WHERE id=" +results[i].id+ ";", function (error, results, fields) {
 .....
```